# How to resolve a MVC controller not found - 404 error

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I can't resolve the 404 I getting and don't understand why I am getting it.

[image]

Requested URL
   http://localhost:55802/AdminFunctions/BlogMaint/BlogMaint/GetActiveBlogCategorys

Physical Path
  F:\Private\Gbng\ProfileAndOrBlog\Development\GbngWebClient\GbngWebClient\AdminFunctions\BlogMaint\BlogMaint\GetActiveBlogCategorys

---

My link in my cshtml that I click:

```
<li>
<a href="/AdminFunctions/BlogMaint/BlogMaint/GetActiveBlogCategorys"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-fw"></i> Blog Maintenance</a>
```

My folder structure is:

[image]

My controller code method: GetActiveBlogCategorys().

[image]

My view folder structure:

[image]

Error: not find view:

[image]

Comment: use ``@Url.Action("GetActiveBlogCategorys", "BlogMaint")`` to generate url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use mvc core

```
<a asp-controller="BlogMaint" asp-action="GetActiveBlogCategorys"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-fw"></i> Blog Maintenance</a>
```

otherwise

```
<a href="@Url.Action("GetActiveBlogCategorys","BlogMaint")">
     <i class="fa fa-edit fa-fw"></i> Blog Maintenance
</a>
```

I don't see you controller, but if you use http post, then need use submit form and this way don't math you.

Comment: show me your controller code and I give you right solution

Comment: I posted the controller method above. the first get method should be executed.

Comment: could you comment out second method with parameter and rest only first without any params and try again.

Comment: On "BlogMaint" (the non-core version),  I get "Missing attribute name". Does not seem to resolve properly. There is an extra </a>. I remove them and I still get the missing issue. It is underlined.

Comment: That worked but it now cannot find my view. I posted the view structure and error above. It does not like my folder structure for sure.

Comment: I tried that. Does not work as it leaves out the 'Adminfunction' part of the path. The view 'GetActiveBlogCategorys' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/BlogMaint/GetActiveBlogCategorys.cshtml

Comment: ok, use that way return View("~/Views/AdminFunctions/BlogMaint/GetActiveBlogCategorys.cshtml");

Comment: Works..I had tried it before but forgot to follow the ~ with /. So all good now.

Comment: Side note. Instead of the @Url.Action solution, I added another route to the RouteConfig.cs to handle the controllers in the AdminFunctions/BlogMaint folder.             routes.MapRoute(
                // The Admin route template.
                name: "Admin",
                url: "AdminFunctions/BlogMaint /{controller}/{action}/{id}"
            );  And then made the href this: <a href="/BlogMaint/GetActiveBlogCategorys"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-fw"></i> Blog Maintenance</a>

Comment: I very glad) You could mark answer as resolved if it helped you

Comment: I have a bunch of other hrefs that are not referencing that AdminFunctions/BlogMaint folder structure so I thought it would be more consistent by adding the route map than using that @Url.Action.

Comment: I did as it was helpful and gives a different approach to solving the problem. Good to know.